# After sideloading .ipa, I don't have provisioning profiles tab in settings and apps are not trusted forever

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, provisioning-profile

It started since iOS 10 beta 2 came out and I installed it. I needed to side-load two apps, plus iOS 10 still felt unstable so I decided to downgraded to get all I needed. Now here is the thing, the apps are getting installed fine, provisioning profiles are suppose to be up till 2017. But when I launch app on iPhone, it tells me I need to allow these app as I am untrusted yet. HOWEVER, the tab with "Profiles" is gone, even though I have 2 apps installed through Xcode. What I have tried so far:

1. Recover
2. Reset everything
3. Upgrade back to iOS 10
4. Some stuff recommended on internet (already out of hope).
5. In Xcode going to Windows tab and in devices deleting those apps and installing again.

I'm really confused over what it could be.

Comment: Nothing in General > Profiles and Device Management?